# How to get data from data frame by using Class in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, class, variables

I have a data frame as below and I would like to use class function to define the data structure.

How can I use a variable to select truck randomly.

For example: if this variable select Truck 1, it will look at the dataframe and return the data corresponding with this truck name. In this case, truck1 has following information:

'idnum' = 1

'trucktype': int

'arrival': = 1

'productlist' = sum of product1 and product2 = (3+2, 5+0, 8+9) = (5,5,17)

```
#Dataframe:
import pandas as pd
dictionary = {
    'TruckName': [1, 2, 3], 
    'Type': ['int','out','out'], 
    'Arrival': [1, 2, 1,],
    'Process': [4,7,8],
    'Product1': [3,5,8],
    'Product2': [2,0,9],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

#define truck:
class Truck:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        if 'idnum' in kwargs:
            self.idnum=kwargs['idnum'] 
        if 'truckType' in kwargs:
            self.truckType=kwargs['truckType']
        if 'productList' in kwargs:
            self.productList=kwargs['productList']
        if 'arrival' in kwargs:
            self.arrival=kwargs['arrival']
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly your problem, but I interpret it as:
Everytime you call a Truck object you want to generate random Truck object, based on properties from the dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

dictionary = {
    'TruckName': [1, 2, 3], 
    'Type': ['int','out','out'], 
    'Arrival': [1, 2, 1,],
    'Process': [4,7,8],
    'Product1': [3,5,8],
    'Product2': [2,0,9],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
variable = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
#define truck:
class Truck:
    def __init__(self, df, variable):
        self.id = variable
        self.idnum = df.loc[self.variable, 'idnum']
        self.truckType = df.loc[self.variable,'truckType']
        self.arrival = df.loc[self.variable,'arrival']
        self.productList = [df.loc[0, "Product1"] + df.loc[0, "Product2"], df.loc[1, "Product1"] + df.loc[1, "Product2"], df.loc[2, "Product1"] + df.loc[2, "Product2]]
        

my_random_truck = Truck(variable, df)
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your code suggestion. However, when I run this code, this has below error: AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I have edited the above response, it should work for you now.